# Smooth scroll Javascript works but messes up flask app

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working on a flask app and in my index.html I have a js file that has a smooth scrolling script in it. The smooth scroll works as far as clicking on links and the page goes to that section nice and smooth, but I have a web form that Im trying to process with flask. When I run the app.py and then go to the url it gives my sites loads, but if I fill out the form and submit nothing happens. I get an error in dev console:

```
uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (main.js:33)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

When I comment out the smooth scroll code and run the app, the form works correctly when I click submit. App.py prints out my data and the success page is loaded. The problem is the smooth scroll but I dont know why, because again it actually does smooth scroll but when the code is active but it wont let the submit work.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b015121141.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" href="../static/css/mobile.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1100px)" href="../static/css/widescreen.css">

  <title>System Services</title>

</head>

<body id="home">
  <nav id="navbar">
    <h1 class="logo">
      <span class="text-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-robot"></i> 
      </span>Systems
    </h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#what">What</a></li>
      <li><a href="#who">Who</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- header: Showcase -->
  <header id="showcase">
    <div class="showcase-content">
      <h1 class="l-heading">
        Take me to your leader
      </h1>
      <p class="lead">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates alias quasi eligendi. Itaque, repudiandae
        obcaecati accusamus harum nesciunt possimus magni?

      </p>
      <a href="#what" class="btn">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </header>


  <!-- Section: Contact-->
  <section id="contact">
    <div class="contact-form bg-primary p-2">
      <h2 class="m-heading">Contact Us</h2>
      <p>Please Use the form below to contact us</p>
      <form action="/submit" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phone">Phone</label>
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message">Message</label>
          <textarea name="message" id="" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-dark">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="map"></div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer id="main-footer" class="bg-dark text-center py-1">
    <div class="container">
      <p>Copyright &copy; 2019, All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- JQuery CDN -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!-- Local Js file -->
  <script src="../static/js/main.js"></script>

  <!-- Google Maps -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[api]&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

success.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Success</title>
</head>

<body>
  <H1>Success!!</H1>
</body>

</html>
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        phone = request.form['phone']
        message = request.form['message']
        print(name, email, phone, message)
        return render_template('success.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

main.js

```
//init and add the map
function initMap() {
  // your location
  const loc = { lat: 42.964890, lng: -88.183040 };
  // centered map on location
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('.map')
    , {
      zoom: 10,
      center: loc
    });
  // the marker, positioned at location
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: loc, map: map });

}
// Sticky menu background
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  if (window.scrollY > 150) {
    document.querySelector('#navbar').style.opacity = 0.88;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#navbar').style.opacity = 1;

  }
})
// Smooth Scrolling
$('#navbar a, .btn').on('click', function (event) {
  if (this.hash !== '') {
    event.preventDefault();

    const hash = this.hash;

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 100
    },
      800
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really related on jquery forum and don't came from flask. Nevertheless, they are solutions :

Solution #1:

Use the native css smooth scroll (works fine in your case in my opinion) --> [Smooth scroll](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section2)

Solution #2 :

Try to call animate() in console of your website and paste it belowthe result to see where the problem came from :)

I hope this will help you I tried on my computer and I can figure any other solutions !

Comment: ok so I removed the smooth scroll js code and added the smooth scroll css and it seems to work pretty good. Thanks, Id still like to figure out why the script breaks things. Again, it did work as far as scrolling goes, it just messed up the functionality of the form for some reason.

Comment: So your problem is solved ? If it is please my answer the 'best answer' because it can help a lot of people which have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have the line `this.hash` inside your `click` event which will always return `""` and that is the reason you are getting the error because you have the hash/id in the `href` attribute of the links and buttons where you are binding the click event

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#what">What</a></li>
    <li><a href="#who">Who</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-dark">
<a href="#what" class="btn">Read More</a>
```

and you just need to change the

```
this.hash
```

to

```
$(this).attr('href')
```

OR

```
this.href
```

your click event should look like this

```
// Smooth Scrolling
$('#navbar a, .btn').on('click', function (event) {
  if (this.href !== '') {
    event.preventDefault();

    const hash = this.href;

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 100
    },
      800
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: ok so I tried this, but then i end up with a few more errors and the links no longer work. the error is: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://127.0.0.1:5000/#what

Comment: @adamg can you show the exact error string that you are getting in the console , which line number is it pointing to